# OpenCV4Android Circular Object Tracking

Tags: android, opencv, geometry

I am new to `OpenCV` and trying to track a circular object using find contours on Android using 3.1.0. I am following the sample color blob detector to write the code, but the `drawContours()` function never draws anything when I run the application. Here is the `onCameraFrame()` function, which is doing all the processing. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: New version of the code: Still does not work as expected. drawContours() draws around any black objects, and the function produces a very noisy result. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGxAv.jpg) is what it now looks like.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Mat processedMat = new Mat(); 
    Imgproc.threshold(grayMat, processedMat, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    List<MatOfPoint> matchedContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat(); 
    Imgproc.findContours(processedMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for(MatOfPoint contour : contours){
        double actualArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
        double width = contour.width();
        double radius = width/2; 
        double calculatedArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);

        if((actualArea - calculatedArea) < 10000) { //chose some arbitrary threshold because I am not sure what to make this
            matchedContours.add(contour);
        }
    }
    Imgproc.drawContours(rgba, matchedContours, -1, new Scalar(0,255,0));
    return rgba; 
}
```

Comment: findContours works on binary images. Use edge detection or thresholding for example before findContours

Comment: I updated my code (above), it now does [this](http://i.imgur.com/fIEjkfr.jpg). The green pixels are the result of drawContours(). This, for some reason, only works on black objects in the camera feed and the program tries to draw around non-circular objects too, which I don't want . [Here](http://i.imgur.com/E0tKPPu.jpg) is what I want to track. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?